# How to manipulate font size "within" an align environment

Tags: amsmath

I'm using the align package for multiple-row equations. Some rows the equations are just a bit longer than the textwidth (I'm using double column). I only want to reduce the fontsize of those particular rows, not the whole align environment. How do I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) i'm just making a stab at a suggestion.  you can use `\text{...}` in an `align` environment, separately for each segment (break points at start/end of line and any `&`), and within `\text` you can specify a size (`\small`, `\Small`, etc.) and then explicitly specify math with `\displaystyle` if appropriate.  it's a hack, but you say you want just some rows, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package provides an `\Aboxed` macro that boxes an equation inside `align` environments (and family) *across* `&`.
The original code is:

```
\newcommand\Aboxed[1]{\let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`}\@Aboxed#1&&\ENDDNE}
\def\@Aboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi \setbox \z@
    \hbox{$\displaystyle#1{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule }%
    \edef\@tempa {\kern  \wd\z@ &\kern -\the\wd\z@ \fboxsep
        \the\fboxsep \fboxrule \the\fboxrule }\@tempa \boxed {#1#2}%
}
```

I’m going to adapt this by measuring the whole width of the equation and re-sizing the whole line to `\linewidth`. This’ll work with `twocolumn`, too, but `showframe` doesn’t show the inner column separator.

In the examples one can see that it works best when the one long line has on both sides of `&` the longest part of all lines.

The equal sign don’t align perfectly because the left part deos’nt end at the left side of `=` (and neither in the middle) but to the left from the additional space that is inserted before the relation sign (i.e. `\thickmuskip`) which will be scaled as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[
%   twocolumn,
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\width@one
\newdimen\width@two
\newdimen\width@onetwo
\newdimen\left@kern
\newcommand\Rboxed[1]{\let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`}\@Rboxed#1&&\ENDDNE}
\def\@Rboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\displaystyle#1{}\m@th$}%
  \setbox1\hbox{$\displaystyle{}#2\m@th$}%
  \width@one=\wd0%
  \width@two=\wd1%
  \width@onetwo=\width@one%
  \advance\width@onetwo by \width@two%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\width@factor}{\linewidth/\width@onetwo}%
  %%% Solution A
%  \pgfmathsetlength{\left@kern}{\width@factor*\width@one}%
%  \edef\@tempa{\kern\left@kern&\kern-\the\left@kern}\@tempa%
%  \scalebox{\width@factor}{$\displaystyle#1{}$}&\scalebox{\width@factor}{$\displaystyle{}#2$}%
%  \resizebox\linewidth!{$#1#2$}%
  %% Solution B
  \edef\@tempb{\noexpand\scalebox{\width@factor}{$\displaystyle#1{}$}&\noexpand\scalebox{\width@factor}{$\displaystyle{}#2$}}%
  \@tempb%
}
\makeatother
%\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = c^2 \\
\Rboxed{long equation + very long equation + long equation + long equation + long equation & = a^2+b^2} \\
c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = c^2 \\
\Rboxed{long equation + very long equation + long equation + long equation & = a^2+b^2 + long equation} \\
c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
\end{align*}

\twocolumn
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = c^2 \\
\Rboxed{long equation + long equation + long & = a^2+b^2} \\
c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = c^2 \\
\Rboxed{long equation + long equation + long & = a^2+b^2 + long equation} \\
c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Without an actual MWE or an use-case, this is an example of “This could work”. I guess that re-writing the formula or `split`ting on two lines is a valid (and maybe better) solution.